# C++ library unstructured mesh writer to VTK format (or similar)

Tags: visualization, unstructured-mesh, paraview, gmsh

I am working on a 2D unstructured code in C++. I am using `gmsh` to generate a 2D unstructured mesh and reading it into my program with a library called `GMSH_IO`. Now that I have the data, I would like to write it to a VTK file for visualization in Paraview.

I could do this manually, but I am curious if anyone knows of a library for writing unstructured meshes to VTK files for visualization?

Comment: Does VTK-m work for you?: https://gitlab.kitware.com/vtk/vtk-m/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking for [Kitware VTK](https://github.com/Kitware/VTK), basically, the main library for interaction with VTK files. [Examples page](https://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx) will contain a lot of samples, including the one you are looking for: [output of an unstructured grid](https://lorensen.github.io/VTKExamples/site/Cxx/IO/WriteVTU/).

As an addition, GMSH itself (I am using 3.0.5) is also able to export the mesh into VTK without the need to go through IO procedure. That can be accessed:

File -> Export -> Save As -> Mesh VTK (*.vtk)

[image]